# apply two consecutive xslt transformations

Tags: xslt

I have two xslt transformations to apply to an xml message.
The first is to drop all namespaces and prefixes. here is the code :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(self::*)]">
  <xsl:copy/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The second one is to select elements from the output of the first :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <onSale><xsl:value-of select="//entry/content/product_product/sale_ok" /></onSale>
        <onlineOnly><xsl:value-of select="//entry/content/product_product/online" /></onlineOnly>
        <name><xsl:value-of select="//entry/content/product_product/name" /></name>
        <isbn><xsl:value-of select="//entry/content/product_product/isbn" /></isbn>
        <price><xsl:value-of select="//entry/content/product_product/price" /></price>
        <active><xsl:value-of select="//entry/content/product_product/active" /></active>
        <format><xsl:value-of select="//entry/content/product_product/format" /></format>
        <collection><xsl:value-of select="//entry/content/product_product/collection" /></collection>
        <dateParution><xsl:value-of select="//entry/content/product_product/date_parution"/></dateParution>
        <ean13><xsl:value-of select="//entry/content/product_product/ean13"/></ean13>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How I can apply the two of them in one xslt transformation without doing two transformation separately .
Thanks

Comment: Do you use an XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 processor? You would need to edit the stylesheets to add a mode and store a temporary result in a variable.

Comment: Yes I'm using it for a xslt mediator in WSO2 ESB server, what I want is just having a single XSLT file who is going to do the 2 transformations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which version of XSLT is supported in your environment, with XSLT 2.0 you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="step1">
 <xsl:apply-templates mode="step1"/>
</xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(self::*)]" mode="step1">
  <xsl:copy/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*" mode="step1">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="step1"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$step1//entry"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entry">
        <onSale><xsl:value-of select="content/product_product/sale_ok" /></onSale>
        <onlineOnly><xsl:value-of select="content/product_product/online" /></onlineOnly>
        <name><xsl:value-of select="content/product_product/name" /></name>
        <isbn><xsl:value-of select="content/product_product/isbn" /></isbn>
        <price><xsl:value-of select="content/product_product/price" /></price>
        <active><xsl:value-of select="content/product_product/active" /></active>
        <format><xsl:value-of select="content/product_product/format" /></format>
        <collection><xsl:value-of select="content/product_product/collection" /></collection>
        <dateParution><xsl:value-of select="content/product_product/date_parution"/></dateParution>
        <ean13><xsl:value-of select="content/product_product/ean13"/></ean13>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would further refactor however and write templates like

```
<xsl:template match="sale_ok">
  <onSale>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </onSale>
</xsl:template>
```

If you use XSLT 1.0 you need an extension function to process the contents of a variable with apply-templates so doing

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="step1">
 <xsl:apply-templates mode="step1"/>
</xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(self::*)]" mode="step1">
  <xsl:copy/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*" mode="step1">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="step1"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($step1)//entry"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entry">
        <onSale><xsl:value-of select="content/product_product/sale_ok" /></onSale>
        <onlineOnly><xsl:value-of select="content/product_product/online" /></onlineOnly>
        <name><xsl:value-of select="content/product_product/name" /></name>
        <isbn><xsl:value-of select="content/product_product/isbn" /></isbn>
        <price><xsl:value-of select="content/product_product/price" /></price>
        <active><xsl:value-of select="content/product_product/active" /></active>
        <format><xsl:value-of select="content/product_product/format" /></format>
        <collection><xsl:value-of select="content/product_product/collection" /></collection>
        <dateParution><xsl:value-of select="content/product_product/date_parution"/></dateParution>
        <ean13><xsl:value-of select="content/product_product/ean13"/></ean13>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On the other I wonder why we are getting lots of questions recently trying to eliminate namespaces or to ignore them, if you really want to do that with XSLT 2.0 then doing

```
<xsl:template match="*:sale_ok">
  <onSale>
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <onSale>
</xsl:template>
```

and so on suffices.